# Как сделать проверку на существования атрибута, в методе мап?

Tags: javascript

Перебираю элементы вот таким образом

```
const img = await page.evaluate(() => {
return [...document.querySelectorAll('section > a')].filter((value, index) => index > 2).map(i => ({
img: i.querySelector('div > div > div > img:nth-child(2)').getAttribute('data-src')}))
})
```

Ну проблема в том, что не у всех айтемов есть getAttribute и я получаю ошибку, что атрибут нал
Как можно сделать проверку, что  если атрибута нет, я мог записать "Картинка не найдена"
Я уже и через иф пробовал и через тернарный оператор ?:, просто не приложу ума как ту это можно сделать

Comment: проверка на null или undefined в JS легко делается через двойное отрицание :) в реакте не силен :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute

Comment: Я проверить и сам могу на наличие. Мне я получаю 50 айтемов, мне надо получить 50 значений атрибута. Если атрибута нет - записать строку в значение.

Comment: @Ijuy23kl ну так проверяйте через if . В чем проблема. Если есть атрибут пишите в переменную значение, нет - пишите в переменную 'картинка не найдена'. Потом переменную в объект подставляете

Comment: Я понимаю как мне это сделать. Я не понимаю как мне это сделать в контексте МАПА. Я перебираю item'ы в мапе, если я i оборачиваю в if то таким образом нельзя задать проверку. Вопрос не в том как мне это сделать, а как мне эту проверку и запись в контексте этого кода. Не придумывая сто костылей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

//варианта первый
let data = [...images].map(image => {
  let src = image.hasAttribute('data-src') ? image.getAttribute('data-src') : 'нет картинки';
  return {img:src};
})

//варианта второй
let data1 = [...images].map(image => {  
  return {img:image.getAttribute('data-src') || 'нет картинки'};
})


console.log(data);
console.log(data1);
```

```html
<img data-src='qwe'>
<img data-src='qwe'>
<img data-src='qwe'>
<img>
<img data-src='qwe'>
<img>
```

Answer (score -1):

Как-то типа так:

```
var item;
const value = ((item = document.querySelector('div')) && item.getAttribute && item.getAttribute('data-src')) || 'blablabla';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin зачем, если и так все понятно в ответе? А если что-то не понятно - есть комментарии. Цитировать и разжевывать "<%language%> для чайников" - ну такое...

Comment: 1. [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) 2. неплохо заранее предугадать, что может вызвать дополнительные вопросы, и изложить это в тексте ответа. 3. как видите, кто-то уже и минус поставил вашему ответу. причины, конечено, не знаю, но не удивлюсь, если это чрезмерная краткость ответа.

Comment: Я проверить и сам могу на наличие. Мне я получаю 50 айтемов, мне надо получить 50 значений атрибута. Если атрибута нет - записать строку в значение.